# How to serve static content in spring boot when servlet path is defined in config

Tags: spring-boot, static-content

I've noticed when specifying servlet path, serving static content doesn't work out of the box. In fact, I haven't been able to get it to work in any way. Here's a part of my application.properties file:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/online
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/app
```

If I comment out `spring.mvc.servlet.path=/app` then I am able to access the styles.css file that's under the `resources/static` folder when I hit the url `localhost:8080/online/styles.css`. But with that config in place, the app throws 404 error. The DispathcherServlet does not handle that request for sure, which AFAIK is the expected behavior. If `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` class is the one to handle it, then its `handleRequest` method misses the request. Any ideas as to what should be done?

Answer (score 1):

`ResourceHttpRequestHandler` is also affected by changing `spring.mvc.servlet.path`, therefore the css will be served as `localhost:8080/online/app/styles.css`